# Opening a react relative path component in a different tab breaks the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following static website built in react running from netlify right now
https://tawsifrafid.com/
I have two components to this. The main Home component and the About component. If you access the site, everything seems to be working. If we go into the About component by clicking on 'About', you can see the About component. But, if we were to to do hard refresh on it, the component breaks. Not only that, when I try to open the About component in a new window or tab, it also breaks at that point.
I checked my local environment where I was testing the website before running it from netlify. The About component is working fine there. It is opening in a new tab or window. If I do a hard refresh, I can still see the About page.
I do not know what I am doing wrong. This is my first react project. For some reason, it can render the components properly in my local device, but cannot render it from the netlify server. I'm not sure how to fix it. It maybe because I'm routing them wrong. My index.js file looks like below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './component/js/App';
import About from './component/js/About'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={App} exact strict />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} exact strict />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

I have no clue about what I am doing wrong. If anyone has any idea or recommendation, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

As in the answer below mentioned, I had to switch over to hashrouter to make it work for now. The only problem with this solution is that the url doesn't look clean as there is a '#' in your url. I'm trying to figure out using Browser history to help with this, as I read somewhere I needed to do that. In the meantime, if anyone had suggestion about how to make it look cleaner, that would be really helpful.

**Updated code**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import App from './component/js/App';
    import About from './component/js/About'
    import './index.css'

    ReactDOM.render((
        <Router>
            <Route path='/' component={App} exact strict />
            <Route path='/about' component={About} exact strict />
        </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because when you click the link client side js changes the url and react itself changes the dom which **CANNOT** happen when you refresh or put the url in the tab directly.

Use a [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter).

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<HashRouter>
  …
</HashRouter>
```

Note that `HashRouter` comes from *`react-router-dom`, not the core `react-router` package*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works, but I was wondering if there was a way to make it work with a nicer url. What I mean is, instead of using www.urlname/#/page, how can I make it www.urlname/page and make it work? I saw many people doing things with express, but I think that's too much for what I'm trying to accomplish